# Reading events from layer 2 blockchains

Tags: events, polygon, arbitrum, zksync, l2

I'm planning to query a tx using a tx hash on Ethereum and get the events/logs to find out the recipient and sender of the ETH.
Is it possible to do so for L2 blockchains like Optimism, ZkSync, Polygon, and Arbitrum?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do so for L2 blockchains like Optimism, ZkSync, Polygon, and Arbitrum?

All [EVM-compatible blockchains](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/evm-compatible) implement Ethereum's original [JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/).

This includes

- Layer 1 chains that are EVM compatible: **Polygon**, BNB Smart Chain, Avalanche C-chain, etc.
- Layer 2: Arbitrum, Optimism, zkSync, etc.

You interact with this JSON-RPC API using libraries like [Web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/) or [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/).

You will need to have a JSON-RPC full node to read the events. Normal nodes do not store event history, especially if you are using crappy public RPC endpoints.

- You can run the node yourself (fastest reading throughput)
- [You can find node service providers at ethereumnodes.com](https://ethereumnodes.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, L2 EVM-compatible chains support the same JSON RPC methods supported by Ethereum.

You essentially do it the same way; you just need to have access to an endpoint for the L2 chain you are interested in.

Here is a list of a few methods that allow you to retrieve transactions information and logs:

- [eth_getTransactionReceipt | Polygon](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/polygon-gettransactionreceipt) (transaction data and logs in the same place)
- [eth_getTransactionByHash | Polygon](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/polygon-gettransactionbyhash)
- [eth_getLogs | Polygon](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/polygon-getlogs)

> These URLs link to the Polygon API reference, but those methods will work the same way on the other networks you mentioned; just use the corresponding endpoint.

Comment: To avoid being flagged as spammer you need to disclose your affiliation https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion.

Comment: The disclosure is in my name :) A mod suggested this a while ago. Plus this is hardly a promotion. Yes, I work for the company but the resources I shared are relevant to the question and useful.

Comment: Thank you David. It's a valuable resource.